# Why does Gulp's uglify not work?

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to uglify my javascript code using gulp. I'm developing a web app in Visual Studio 2015 and we've got a bunch of task scripts in gulpfile.js. Here's a snippet of the script that packages all our javascript into a file called app.js and how I'm trying to uglify it:

```
gulp.task('dev:js', ['lint'], function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.appjs)
        .pipe(plugins.order([
            'Shared/PartialViews/_mainLayout.js',
           'Shared/shared.js',
           '*'
        ]))
        .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())     // <-- Uglification
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs));
});
```

But it's not working. When I run the application, open the Chrome console, I still see app.js in its prettified perfectly legible form.

This same method works for other files, for example our vandor.js file:

```
gulp.task('vendor:js', ['install'], function() {
    return gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.order([
            'jquery.js',
            'bootstrap.js',
            'jquery.dataTables.js',
            'dataTables.bootstrap.js',
            'dataTables.responsive.js',
            'responsive.bootstrap.js',
            'dataTables.select.js',
            'pnotify.js',
            '*'
        ]))
        .pipe(plugins.debug({ title: 'vendor-files:' }))
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())     // <-- Uglification
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs));
});
```

Why wouldn't the same work for app.js?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you need to save file after the concatinating process and then uglify and save again. Like this:

```
gulp.task('vendor:js', ['install'], function() {
    return gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.order([
            'jquery.js',
            'bootstrap.js',
            'jquery.dataTables.js',
            'dataTables.bootstrap.js',
            'dataTables.responsive.js',
            'responsive.bootstrap.js',
            'dataTables.select.js',
            'pnotify.js',
            '*'
        ]))
        .pipe(plugins.debug({ title: 'vendor-files:' }))
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())     // <-- Uglification
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs));
});
```

Comment: Um... that's the one that DOES work. If I add an extra line saving to paths.distJs to the one that doesn't work, the script crashes. Same if I add it to the one that DOES work.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I've misunderstood code somehow. Anyway I had similar build before and saving files before uglifying them resolved my issue, sorry to hear that it doesn't help you.